# How to read in from a file and create new objects with input from the read file

Tags: java, file, hashmap

Read in students file. For each student ID create a Student object. Set that objects name to the name in the file after the student ID. Add the Student object to the map with the student ID as the key.
Read in courses file. For each student ID, lookup the Student object from the map. Read the credit hour line in the file. Read the grade line in the file. Create a Course object using the credit hour and grade. Add that Course object to the Student object's collection of courses.

Here is my code which reads in the information from the file:

```
    FileReader freader = new FileReader(nameFile);
    BufferedReader Breader = new BufferedReader(freader);
    boolean end = Breader.ready();

        do {
            next = Breader.readLine();
            sNumber = Integer.parseInt(next);
            formatSNumber = String.format("%03d", sNumber);
            //Assignment the formatted number to my HashMap
            sName = Breader.readLine();
            //Assignment the name to my HashMap
            end = Breader.ready();
        } while(end);
```

I am completely lost on how to do this.

I know how to create a student object:

```
Student student1 = new Student();
```

However, I need each name, "student1", to be different depending upon the information read in.

For example, if I read "001" and "Julie Jones", I want my student object to be

```
Student student1 = new Student();
```

And then the next one to be

```
Student student2 = new Student();
```

For Student studenti = new Student();, where i = the number of student IDs read in from the file.

Comment: What is `Breader`? This class is not part of the standard JDK.

Comment: It's an instance of BufferedReader. Sorry, I added some code for clarity.

Comment: Hah, breader.  Well, first off, you need to create a student object, yes?

Comment: *create a Student object* If this is beyond your ability then I suggest getting some one-on-one tuition

Comment: Ok, that's easy:

Student student1 = new Student();

HOWEVER, I need the name, "student1", to be different for each number of student IDs read it, which can be several.

Comment: There must be hundreds of examples on how to read in a text file that can be found just on SO

Comment: Alright, you need to narrow down your question then.  you said your were "completely lost".  Ask your question more specifically.

Comment: You do not need to have different variables names for your `Student` **BECAUSE** every time that your loop iterates it re-declares the Student object and the code re-initialises the values that will be stored in the Student Object.  These objects can within the loop be added to an `ArrayList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo, I think the question is a bit misleading.  "objects name" means students name-- not the name of the objects reference variable.  What I'm reading is that you will need to create a student object with their Name passed in as a parameter.

I think it should be something like this (psudocode):

```
//create a map//
for each line in file {
    int id=//GET THE ID//
    String name=//GET THE STUDENTS NAME//
    Student student=new Student(name);
    map.add(student, id);
}
```